# FileNotFoundException: Unable to read anonymization settings, not reporting any values: /Users/mac/.android/analytics.settings (Permission denied)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using latest version of Android Studio on Mac. Whenever I open the app it shows me the above error. Can anyone help me in resolving it? Here is a picture as well:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem here, but into ubuntu 16.04.

Based on @madhan's comment I saw that the permissions of my .android was only for root user, so I did change the owner for that folder and that's it.

I used this command for change the folder owner:

sudo chown -R davidg:davidg .android/

Please replace "davidg:davidg" with your own user.

All working fine now.

I supose that at the first android studio start, it creates the file "analytics.settings" and maybe others into this folder but if permission is not granted for the user running the IDE then shows this error.

I hope this help you.

[Before change the owner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkpCT.png)

[After change the owner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsJto.png)

Answer (score 4):

step1: find .android folder in my case it is in /home/pravin
if you dont find it press ctrl+h to view the hidden folders

step2: pravin@pravin:~$ sudo chmod 777 /home/pravin/.android

just restart android studio
done

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, but I have found temporary solution that is :
if we open the android studio by the command 'sudo' like : `sudo ./studio.sh` then this error will not be there. But as I said it is one way and it is temporary, I also don't know the main solution. But I am sure that you have Android/Sdk in different directory then android/studio/bin (as I do), and I think that is the reason. Plus some extra settings needed in android studio.